# How to send email in flutter withouth open a email app?

Tags: flutter, email, dart

I'm newest in flutter.
I need help.
In one of the pages of my application, I need to send an email without opening the email application itself.
I'll explain.
I have a bug report page. For example, I need to send an email because a package has not been returned.
After filling out a form with my personal data, I need to automatically send an email.

I tried with url_lanch and mailer but either nothing happens or the gmail app opens (in the android emulator).
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

use mailer package [mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer) to send mail. and also can make custom template using http package from the same site.